# Vue.js prevents the function of iframe

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe, vue.js

I have been encountering a very strange issue where I am in the need of having an iframe inside of a vue template, and then to edit this iframe later on. I have managed to reduce this down to the following code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <iframe id="testFrame" src="javascript:''" width="500" height="500">
      </iframe>
      <!-- This iframe is coming from the rails `yield` helper function. However this is the MCVE of our problem. -->
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var doc = document.getElementById('testFrame').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write('<html><head><title></title></head><body>Hello world.</body></html>');
doc.close();
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The generated iframe however is shown here:

[image: Current, incorrect iframe.]

However the desired behavior is to have the text rendered as seen below:

[image]

What would be causing this problem, and how would I best go about fixing it? (Please take note this is an extremely simplified version Minimum Complete Verifiable Example, of a very large rails application I am working on. )

Comment: Vue 1.x or 2.x?  My initial thought is that when the template is mounted, it's going to totally replace the `<iframe>` you have in your `<div>` tag.  I think the `<iframe>` needs to be part of the template (if that's even possible).  Just a guess.

Comment: It is version 2.0, unfortunately it is not really possible to move it all into vue templates as this is just an extremely simplified version. The actual application is using a mix of webpack,  yarn,  vue,   rails,  tinymce, and a few other software packages.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but does adding `v-pre` to the `iframe` help?

Comment: @BillCriswell Nope, doesn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is XSS. Browsers don't allow this.